# MySQL trigger for change detection

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have several tables in the database: `Users, Profiles, Articles`

I also have one table called `Changes`, which is used for administrative purposes. This table consists of `id, table_name, and date_created`.
What I need to do is whenever something is added, deleted or updated in a regular table (`Users, Profiles, Articles`), create a new row in the `Changes` with the name of the updated table and the current timestamps.

I've been browsing for a while and tried many different methods, but nothing really worked. I know the solution should be very simple, may be someone can help me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html ?

Comment: from your answer I understand that I was two mistakes away from the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case you need 9 trigger 3 for each of the regular table `after insert`, `after update`, `after delete`

Here is for one table you can write for the others

*When you insert on `Users`*

```
delimiter //
create trigger log_user_insert after insert on Users
for each row 
begin
  insert into Changes (table_name,date_created) values ('Users',now());
end; //

delimiter ;
```

*When update  happens on `Users`*

```
delimiter //
create trigger log_user_update after update on Users
for each row 
begin
  insert into Changes (table_name,date_created) values ('Users',now());
end; //

delimiter ;
```

*When delete happens on `Users`*

```
delimiter //
create trigger log_user_update after delete on Users
for each row 
begin
  insert into Changes (table_name,date_created) values ('Users',now());
end; //

delimiter ;
```

I would suggest to add a column called `action` in the table `Changes` and to insert each action name as well i.e. insert,update and delete.

Comment: OMG, it seem to work! 'Dobby is free' :) Now I can have some sleep. Thank you, man!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an update, insert and delete trigger on each of the data tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_changes_users BEFORE UPDATE ON Users
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO changes (table_name, date_created) VALUES ('users', NOW());
 END;
```

This code assumes, that the id column in `changes` is auto_generated. You might also want to consider including a `type` column in the `changes` table (to differentiate between insert, update and delete).